# windows11 - ai.exe is locking a folder that needs to be routinely deleted

Tags: windows-11, process, locked-files

I have a folder that routinely needs to be deleted by a program and remade. It's simply how the program works. Suddenly a short while back, the program stopped being able to delete the folder. I tried deleting it manually and was also unable, as the folder was busy.
I ran the resource monitor and found that the process stopping the deletion is called ai.exe, a file used by all MS Office programs.
The folder in question never has any ms office files in it so I am at a loss to how this folder was chosen to be locked in such a way.
Is there a way to define for the process folders it should ignore?
Or any other solution.
Thanks!

Comment: If you reboot, does the problem come back? Maybe its just a one-time quirck.

Comment: @LPChip persists